# Elseif conditions for dynamic multifilter in an ajax call do not show expected results

Tags: ajax, if-statement

I am trying to set up a dynamic multifilter with 4 different selects, written with Semantic UI (set up with multiple choices).

Selects:
Status
Region
Country
Area Names

My basic conditions are as follows (since it is an ajax I write the debugging test on a file):

```
  if (!empty($selectedStatus)) {
            $query_area_name .= " test 0";
            file_put_contents('somefilename.txt', "Condition: Test 0: Status selected \n", FILE_APPEND);
            if (empty($selectedRegions) && empty($selectedCountries)) {
                $query_area_name .= " test 1";
                file_put_contents('somefilename.txt', "Condition: Test 01: Status selected AND Region not selected AND Country not selected \n", FILE_APPEND);
            }
            elseif (!empty($selectedRegions) && empty($selectedCountries)) {
                $query_area_name .= " test 1";
                file_put_contents('somefilename.txt', "Condition: Test 1: Status selected AND Region selected AND Country not selected \n", FILE_APPEND);
            }
            elseif (empty($selectedRegions) && !empty($selectedCountries)) {
                $query_area_name .= " test 2";
                    file_put_contents('somefilename.txt', "Condition: Test 2: Status selected AND Region not selected AND Country selected \n", FILE_APPEND);
            }
            elseif(!empty($selectedRegions) && !empty($selectedCountries)) {
                $query_area_name .= " test 3";
                    file_put_contents('somefilename.txt', "Condition: Test 3: Status selected AND Region selected AND Country selected  \n", FILE_APPEND);
            }
        } else  {
            if(empty($selectedRegions) && empty($selectedCountries)) {
                $query_area_name .= " test 4";
                    file_put_contents('somefilename.txt', "Condition: Test 04: Status not selected AND Region not selected AND Country not selected  \n", FILE_APPEND);
            }
            elseif(!empty($selectedRegions) && empty($selectedCountries)) {
                $query_area_name .= " test 4";
                    file_put_contents('somefilename.txt', "Condition: Test 4: Status not selected AND Region selected AND Country not selected  \n", FILE_APPEND);
            }
            elseif(empty($selectedRegions) && !empty($selectedCountries)) {
                $query_area_name .= " test 5";
                    file_put_contents('somefilename.txt', "Condition: Test 5: Status not selected AND Region not selected AND Country selected  \n", FILE_APPEND);
            }
            elseif(!empty($selectedRegions) && !empty($selectedCountries)) {
                $query_area_name .= " test 6";
                    file_put_contents('somefilename.txt', "Condition: Test 6: Status not selected AND Region selected AND Country selected  \n", FILE_APPEND);
            }
        }
```

So I expect that if

```
Status selected -> test 0
Status selected AND Region selected -> test 1
Status selected AND Region selected AND Country selected -> test 3
Status not selected (or deselected) AND Region selected AND Country selected -> test 6
etc.
```

Instead I have the following (arrows `=>` show the sequence of selecting actions)

```
Status => region => country
Condition: Test 0: Status selected  -> expected (test 0)
Condition: Test 4: Status not selected AND Region selected AND Country not selected  -> not expected (test 1)
Condition: Test 6: Status not selected AND Region selected AND Country selected  -> not expected (test 3)

Deselect country => deselect region => deselect imma
Condition: Test 6: Status not selected AND Region selected AND Country selected   -> not expected (test 1)
Condition: Test 4: Status not selected AND Region selected AND Country not selected   -> not expected (test 0)
Condition: Test 0: Status selected 

region => country
Condition: Test 4: Status not selected AND Region selected AND Country not selected    -> expected (test 4)
Condition: Test 6: Status not selected AND Region selected AND Country selected   -> expected (test 6)

Deselect country => deselect region
Condition: Test 6: Status not selected AND Region selected AND Country selected  -> not expected (test 4)
Condition: Test 4: Status not selected AND Region selected AND Country not selected  -> not expected (test 04)
```

So basically there may be a logical mistake in my if .. elseif conditions. I tried several ways but in never came out.